# Read HD from mac on ubuntu 17.04

Tags: permissions, mac

I've a HD from my old mac and i'll try to get access to my old Documents

I've tried with `sudo mount -t hfsplus -o remount,force,rw /media/abc/drive/` or `sudo mount -t hfsplus -o force,rw /dev/sdb3 /media/abc/drive/`
but still not working...

I've tried also chmod or chown but nothing to do, how I can enter in this folder?